# Remove .php extention add slash & redirect to www with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to make seo friendly url using .htaccess no .php or html extention. Also auto redirect to https://www end URL with a trailing slash.

I have php page:
- index.php
- product.php
- about.php
- contact.php
- network.php

Final access i want like ***https:// www.mydomain.com/product/***

**Webserver apache 2.4.6**

I try but image, css, js, font, other php/html file not working

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove file extensions, add a trailing slash.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please learn how to ask questions here. SO is _not_ a free coding service, we are not here to do your work for you. Sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Sorry if my question not friendly

Comment: All fine ;-) This is not about friendlyness at all! You added your attempt, great, and actually you also added some very important details that give the question some completely new direction. With such specific information people here can actually help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can this rule to remove .php and to enforce https on your Apache 2.4

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^off#(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#remove .php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

To fix your css, js and other relative resources, just add the following base tag to head section of your webpage

```
<base href="/">
```